# setStreetView() in android 4.0

Tags: android

SetStreetView() method in Android 4.0 is deprecated. So can anyone tell if there is any alternative in Android 4.0 or we can't set the mode to setStreetView() anymore? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

On the Android Map API, there is no way of switching the device to the famous "Street View". The only options available to us developer (on the Android platform) are the classic 2D view and the Satellite view which can be enabled with the `setSatellite(true)` method.

If you read closely the [`setStreetView`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setStreetView%28boolean%29) method doesn't actually switch to Street View, it simply shows the blue line on the streets and boulevards where Street View is actually available:

> Control whether Street View availability *(blue outlines) is shown on
>   the map*. This is incompatible with Traffic indicators, so they will
>   be deactivated if necessary. Street View availability can be drawn
>   over map tiles or over satellite tiles; however, they are optimized
>   for map tiles.

If your intention was to only show the blue lines, well the method has been **deprecated** and there are no known alternatives to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this via a toggle button, works for me.

```
if(map.isSatellite())
{                       
      map.setSatellite(false);                          
}
else
{
      map.setSatellite(true);
}
```